# Whatsapp chat conversation email

Tags: email, whatsapp-messenger

I tried exporting my whatsapp conversation via email. 
This conversation is received to mail box in .txt file attachment. 
Once the file is downloaded to pc and opend with notepad as usual, the chat messages with our local language (hindi, india) are not displayed. Only square boxes are displayed in notepad. (making the conversation backup useless)
What i need to do so that all the messages are displayed in pc ? 
(Eng msg are displayed correctly)(emoji not displayed is ok for me)

regards

Comment: Would you mind listing exactly what you did to export the conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Your system doesn't support Devanagari fonts. If you're using Windows, install the fonts from Microsoft Support.

Update:

- Download [this](http://d-h.st/hVvo)(press the big blue `Download Now` button)
- Open the downloaded file and click on`Install` button(requires administration privileges)
- Open the log, and select encoding as UTF-8

Update#2:
For details on how to set the encoding to UTF-8:
 - click on the 
    File menu - click on save as - on the drop down menu beside the field encoding, select

```
CHARSET UTF-8
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts SE.  Can you post a link to show that that phone doesn't support those fonts?  Adding sources will help garner more votes for your answer.

Comment: Not the phone. The computer.

Comment: thanx Sinchan..  will you please guide what font i need and where will i get that font? (hindi and marathi )

Comment: Check the updated post. I've added the required things.

Comment: i downloaded the file and is downloaded as TTF font file. So there was no install button. (Font added through control panel-Fonts-Install New Fonts) The LOG and Select UTF-8 ..? where should i look for them ?

Comment: See the updated post